# Excel - Reference to dynamic array function in multiple condition (AND/OR)

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

Whenever I use reference to dynamic array function in Excel in multiple condition (AND/OR) it is not working properly (usually it will not spill). I have SEQUENCE function in column "A" and I would like to mark any rows between 5 to 9. Formula looks like this: =IF(AND(A1#>5;A1#<9);"x";""). Any idea how to fix this? Or is it a bug in Excel (or some logic why this is not possible I do not see).

Comment: please show the formula you tried.

Comment: =IF(AND(A1#>5);"x";"") - I know there is AND not necessary but I was testing this on very simply formula - when I use it without AND then it is working, with AND it will not split (In column "A" is function SEQUENCE

Comment: It is hard to know how to fix the formula to do what you want when you do not show an actual formula.  the answer to that formula is to remove the `AND`.  if you want help you need to show an actual formula that you intend to use.  And use [edit] to put the clarifications in the question post not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

When using array formula, either Dynamic or forced one cannot use `AND` or `OR`.  We need to either use `*` or `+` respectively.

In this case with OR:

```
=IF((A1#>5)+(A1#<9);"x";"")
```

For AND:

```
=IF((A1#>5)*(A1#<9);"x";"")
```

Comment: Thx that is exactly what I needed :)